# function pointer as input parameter for templated class function

Tags: c++, templates

I got a piece of code as follows:

```
 template <typename T>
 class Ordered_list{
 public:
     Ordered_list(bool (*less_than_function)(const T&, const T&)): less_than(less_than_function){}

 private:
     bool (*less_than) (const T&, const T&);
 };

 bool less_than_f(const int& i1, const int& i2){
     return i1 < i2;
 }   

 class Collection{
 public:
     Ordered_list<int> list(less_than_f);
 };
```

The code doesn't compile, and I got the error:

```
test.cpp:16: error: 'less_than_f' is not a type
```

I was trying to create a object for the Ordered_list class, which I need to pass in a function pointer. I tried to google for the reason, but didn't get much. Can anybode tell me what should I do to make it work?

Comment: Maybe you're missing the `typename` keyword. Try `typename bool (*less_than_function)(const T&, const T&)`. Read about the [dependant names](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/02/06/dependent-name-lookup-for-c-templates/).

Comment: Thats not a proper instance variable decl. Try putting that in a code block.

Comment: For "function pointers" in C++, I recommend you look into [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster That’s invalid here. Why would you use `typename` here?

Comment: As for your problem, please read e.g. [this article](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html).

Comment: @KonradRudolph if `less_than_function` is a dependant name due the parameter templates maybe `typename` is needed somewhere... `typename bool (*less_than_function)(typename const T&, typename const T&)`, I'm not skilled enough to determine in one sight.

Comment: Side note: Just for convenience (and readability) I'd recommend to typedef the less_than_function signature.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Ah ok. No, this isn’t a dependent name. `typename` is only required when the compiler cannot figure out whether a dependent name is a type name without instantiating the template. That’s not the case here: the compiler knows that `T` names a type. If OP had used `T::Something`, then `Something` would have been a dependent name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Collection{
  public:
    Ordered_list<int> list(less_than_f);
 };
```

Here you are declaring a function with return `Ordered_list<int>` and take a nonamed parametr of type `less_than_f` (Opss! no type), while you want to have a member "`list`". You need to initializate it in the initialization list of the constructor (because  `Ordered_list` dont have a default constructor) [hmm.. not sure about C++11 new options to initialize, but not now in VC2012].

```
 class Collection{
  public:
    Ordered_list<int> list;
    Collection (): list(less_than_f){} 
    explicit Collection (   bool (*less_than_function)(const int& i1, const int& i2)   )
       : list(less_than_function)  {}
   };
```

Answer (score 2):

Your member variable  is not being declared properly. It cannot be initialized as you have it in a declaration.

Try this:

```
 class Collection
 {
 public:
     Collection() : list(less_than_f) {}

     Ordered_list<int> list;
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

Class members can only be initialised in their declaration using a brace initialiser:

```
Ordered_list<int> list {less_than_f};
```

or using `=`:

```
Ordered_list<int> list = less_than_f;
```

(although the latter only works because your constructor isn't `explicit`).

Before 2011 (and, at the time of writing, in most available compilers), non-static class members couldn't be initialised in their declaration at all; a constructor was needed:

```
Collection() : list(less_than_f) {}
```